# Invoke java script function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Need to invoke a client java script function from amp script.

Having a java script function which shows the div element when you have records for the user.

Comment: Please post some code and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side javascript works the same.  You'll just put it in a script tag.  If you need to use server-side js, [check this out](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/using_server_side_javascript_with_ampscript/).